# Where to put comments, class declaration or constructor?

Tags: c#, comments

For a given class, where should the comments about the purpose of the class go?

```
/// <summary>
///       <----------------- describe the class here (1)?
/// </summary>
public class Message
{
  ...
  //class members here
  ...
  /// <summary>
  ///      <--------------- or here (2)?
  /// </summary>
  public Message()
  {
  }
}
```

If I go with the first option, the purpose of the class is very easy to find when I open the file, it's in the same place, on approximately the same line. When you have lots of classes, this is easier for the eyes. You don't have to scroll down past the members to find the constructor

If I go with the second option, I get Intellisense when creating an object of the class, stating it's purpose and explaining the parameters, which is very nice.

From what I can tell, I can't get both advantages by using just one method. The only solution I can think of is putting the same comment in both places, but that's just duplicate information and I don't like it.

Comment: you put it at the class (option 1), this is the expected place for most documentation generators

Comment: Yes, Doxygen puts the comment in the docs with option 1, and that's nice. But VS won't give me any info when creating an object of the class, which I get with option 2, and which I also like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are /// comment blocks important?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5916/why-are-comment-blocks-important)

Comment: @gnat, I'm already using the /// comment blocks. I just don't know where to put them. I've changed my code example to better reflect this. From the selected answer: _[..]They can essentially see all the documentation for your method or class without having to go to the file itself to figure out what it does_. Yeah, problem is, I can't if I'm choosing the (1) method, as ratchet freak sugested

Comment: For c# you put class description in (1) while in the constructor you explain what that constructor does. You might want download and run StyleCop it has some warning on documentation too. For example constructor documentation should start with: "Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="YourClassName"/> class." Note some StyleCop suggestion are somewhat invasive, but at least they give you the idea on what documentation might look like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The purpose of the class should be described above the class name.

A documentation above the constructor is to document differences between the different constructors of the class and what the parameters passed to the constructor(s) do.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly devil's advocate position:

**Neither position.**

The *name* of the class should tell the reader its purpose. If it doesn't, find a better name.

Comment: this does not answer the question asked

Comment: @gnat [On answering the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45536), [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891) - I am *sure* you will have seen these and more...

Comment: sure: _'consider also to answer the actual question, too. As in 
*"Don't do it because of A, B and C. But if you decide to do it anyway, I would follow this approach:..."*'_

Comment: Sure, comments *can* be an antipattern, and good naming is vital.  It's *great* when good naming can replace comments, but "no comments" is an ivory tower rule.  Almost all programming languages, while extremely expressive, are fixed by a spec with strict syntax.  It's often more concise and readable to use natural language to express concepts in a comment, *especially* when commenting for structured docs like JavaDoc, Doxygen, or Sphinx.  (Also, what happens when you're forced into a poorly named framework or library? EX: Uncommented Swing projects are almost completely unmaintainable.)